# Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined / Uncaught TypeError: $(...).daterangepicker is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I tried to display jquery datepicker to my webpage but it giving 2 errors :

1. `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined`
2. `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).daterangepicker is not a function`

looks like I missed something

I'm using jquery 3.3.1.min.js and datepicker.js

here's the code in html and head

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url('') }}/assets/header_css/bootstrap.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url('') }}/assets/header_js/daterangepicker.js"></script>
```

here's the code for input type

```
<input type="text" value ="YYYY/MM/DD" class="form-control datepicker" v-model="tanggalpickup"  name="tanggalpickup" id="tanggalpickup"/>
```

here's the code for the javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input.datepicker").singleDatePicker();
  });

  $.fn.singleDatePicker = function() {
    $(this).on("apply.daterangepicker", function(e, picker) {
      picker.element.val(picker.startDate.format(picker.locale.format));
    });
    return $(this).daterangepicker({
      locale: {
        format: 'YYYY-MM-DD' // Change to local formats YYYY-MM-DD - MM-DD-YYYY
      },
      singleDatePicker: true,
      autoUpdateInput: false
    });
  };
```

all your responses will be highly appreciated

Comment: How are you importing jQuery? It doesn't seem like DatePicker is registered correctly with jQuery.

Comment: *Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined* means `$` is undefined which means jquery has not been included at this point - ensure jquery is included before your code.   `daterangepicker.js` will likely *require* jquery, but not *include* jquery, you need another `<script src=...jquery.js`

Comment: thanks VLAZ and freedomn-m you're right i supposed put the script js not in the head html but after the body

Comment: it's working now

Answer (score 2):

The reason is the library `datepicker` is not initialized correctly. When you add libraries which are using `jQuery`, You need to add those after `jQuery`.

The code should be like,

```
<script src='yourpath/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='yourpath/daterangepicker.js'></script>
```